# wp_logout() changes in WordPress 5.1.1

Tags: logout

We've recently just upgraded our WordPress site to `5.1.1`

After the upgrade, we've started encountering issues when executing the `wp_logout()` function of WordPress. Somehow we're getting a `302` response but there is no error/warning being shown.

I've narrowed it inside the `wp_logout()` and determined that both `wp_destroy_current_session();` and `wp_clear_auth_cookie();` are working fine!

This means that the error happens when the last line in `wp_logout()` is called:

```
do_action( 'wp_logout' );
```

My question is:

> Is it possible to for external plugins to somehow corrupt the `wp_logout` action with functions that can break the flow and give a `302` or is there anything in `5.1.1` that affected `wp_logout` somehow?

Comment: Welcome to WordPress StackExchange! I'd try to narrow this down in a copy of the affected site. Switch of plugins one by one and retest.

Comment: 302 is used at times to redirect users

Comment: Well yes. `add_action( 'wp_logout', function() { wp_redirect( home_url() ); die(); });` would do it.

Answer (score 2):

A lot has changed in 5.1/5.1.1, but the changes I'm seeing in WordPress core wouldn't cause 302 redirects on their own.

### 1. `wp_logout` is pluggable

`wp_logout` is a [pluggable function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions). That means anyone can override this function and cause it to do something different because the function is wrapped in a condition checking for other functions with the same name. Here's the contents of `wp_logout`:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_logout' ) ) :
    wp_destroy_current_session();
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();

    /**
     * Fires after a user is logged-out.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_logout' );
endif;
```

### 2. `wp_logout` calls a `do_action` hook

The last part of the function is calling a `do_action` which anyone can use to add to the function, including redirects.

### 3. `wp_logout` calls other functions

`wp_logout` calls `wp_destroy_current_session` and `wp_clear_auth_cookie`. Either of these could complicate things as well. `wp_destroy_current_session` is able to be modified to use other systems like Redis storage or other methods via the `session_token_manager` filter. `wp_clear_auth_cookie` is a pluggable function and also has a `do_action` hook.

### So, to answer your question...

> WordPress 5.1.1 didn't change anything that would cause a call to `wp_logout()` to throw a 302 redirect, but there are plenty of opportunities for other plugins or themes to cause this to occur.